# ¿Por qué no muestra todas las columnas?

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

Tengo la siguiente consulta en `SQL` pero solo trae 4 ***columnas***:

```
SELECT venta_boleta.numero_bol,
       detalle_boleta.codigo_producto,
       detalle_boleta.cantidad,            
       detalle_boleta.costo,
       productos.nombre_producto,
       marcas.nombre_marca
  FROM detalle_boleta
 INNER JOIN productos
    ON detalle_boleta.codigo_producto = productos.codigo_producto
 INNER JOIN venta_boleta
    ON detalle_boleta.numero_bol = venta_boleta.numero_bol
 INNER JOIN marcas
    ON productos.id_marca = marcas.id_marca
 WHERE detalle_boleta.numero_bol = '4'
```

### Tabla: marcas

```
id_marca // clave primaria 

nombre_marca
```

### Tabla: Productos

```
codigo_producto //clave primaria
nombre_producto
id_marca  // clave primaria de la tabla marcas
id_cat    // clave primaria de la tabla categorias
estado_producto 
precio_costo
precio_venta
stock_minimo    
stock_maximo    
stock_real
src
```

### Tabla: venta_boleta

```
numero_bol //clave primaria

rut_usu //clave primaria de la tabla usuarios

fecha_bol

[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][1]][1]condiciones
```

### Tabla: detalle_boleta

```
id_db //clave primaria

numero_bol // clave primaria de la tabla venta_boleta

codigo_producto // clave primaria de la tabla prodcutos

cantidad

sub_total
```

### Resultado que muestra

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Cuéntanos un poco más detalladamente porque consideras que tu consulta al traer solo 4 registros sea un error, ¿Qué información tienen las otras tablas? revisa tu `WHERE` y prueba cambiando los `INNER` por `LEFT`

Comment: Acabo de agregar mas detalles para que se entienda

Comment: @CristianOx21: ¿Qué sucede si reordenas las columnas en tu `select`? ¿Cambia algo?

Comment: Si, se muestran los 4 primeros campos solamente, dependiendo de cuales sean los cuatro primero campos que seleccione en la consulta, estos serán  los que se mostraran, y no se por que sucede ...

Comment: El problema debe ser la configuración entonces. Fijate que en algun lado debe estar configurado que se muestren solo 4 campos.

Comment: recuerda que estas utilizando inner join, por lo cual solo te van a salir los items que tienen datos en las 4 tablas si no tiene datos en una sola tabla este no saldra, yo te recomendaria fueras haciendo el select join por join, o bien colorar puros left outer join, para que te mande todos los que tienes en tu primera tabla.

Answer (score 0):

Utiliza OUTER JOIN

```
SELECT venta_boleta.numero_bol,
       detalle_boleta.codigo_producto,
       detalle_boleta.cantidad,            
       detalle_boleta.costo,
       productos.nombre_producto,
       marcas.nombre_marca
  FROM detalle_boleta
 OUTER JOIN productos
    ON detalle_boleta.codigo_producto = productos.codigo_producto
 OUTER JOIN venta_boleta
    ON detalle_boleta.numero_bol = venta_boleta.numero_bol
 OUTER JOIN marcas
    ON productos.id_marca = marcas.id_marca
 WHERE detalle_boleta.numero_bol = '4'
```